# I'm getting this error in KMM: Cannot add a KotlinSourceSet with name 'iosMain' as a KotlinSourceSet with that name already exists

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm getting the error in KMM, trying to add the ktor library. It says to add in iOS main, but if I add that it shows this error:

> Cannot add a KotlinSourceSet with name 'iosMain' as a KotlinSourceSet
> with that name already exists.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    targetHierarchy.default()

    android {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }

        dependencies {
            implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.5")
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val ktorVersion = "2.3.5"
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation(compose.foundation)
                implementation(compose.material)
                @OptIn(org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
                implementation(compose.components.resources)
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }

        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)

            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }

        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.tippu.sheriff"
    compileSdk = 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of this line `targetHierarchy.default()`

When you use default target Hierarchy, it automatically adds some sourceSets based on the target you've set. Since you've added iOS targets `iosX64(), iosArm64(), iosSimulatorArm64()`, the plugin added `iosMain` based on that.

Read more about it here in [1.9.20 docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew-eap.html#template-for-configuring-multiplatform-projects). Note that you don't even need `targetHierarchy.default()` with 1.9.20. This feature is now enabled by default in latest version.

Replace you code with this and it should most likely work,

```kotlin
val iosMain by getting {
    dependencies {
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:$ktorVersion")
    }
}
```